# Goutte / crawler regex to find dynamic id

Tags: php, web-scraping, goutte

I am attempting to scrape a page that is kind of a hot mess -- there are three ids I know that I need, but while the different items all have the same ids, i.e. "name", "desc", they have a random(to me) number tacked on. So the below code works for one specific item but not any others. Is there a way to filter using regex with Goutte to get what I need?

```
    $meta = $crawler->filter('#name_312 a')->each(function ($node) {
        return [
            'link' => $node->attr('href'),
        ];
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use css instead of regex.

For example:

`"[id*=name]"` - selects all elements with that have `name` in `id`.

`"[id*=name] a, [id*=desc] a"` - selects all `a` elements that have parent with an `id` that contains `name` or `desc` in his value.